# How to customize headers and column widths of DataFrame display?

Tags: pandas

As a rule, I like to use long, descriptive column names (e.g. `estimated_background_signal` rather than just `bg`) for `DataFrame` objects.  The one downside of this preference is that the `DataFrame`'s display form has several columns that are much wider than their values require.  For example:

```
In [10]: data.head()
     barcode estimated_background_signal inhibitor_code inhibitor_concentration
0  R00577279                         133            IRB                   0.001
1  R00577279                         189            SNZ                   0.001
2  R00577279                         101            CMY                   0.001
3  R00577279                         112            BRC                   0.001
4  R00577279                         244            ISB                   0.001
```

It would be nice if the display were narrower.  Disregarding the headers, the narrowest display would be:

```
0 R00577279 113 IRB 0.001
1 R00577279 189 SNZ 0.001
2 R00577279 101 CMY 0.001
3 R00577279 112 BRC 0.001
4 R00577279 244 ISB 0.001
```

...but eliminating the headers altogether is not an entirely satisfactory solution.  A better one would be to make the display wide enough to allow for some headers, possibly taking up several lines:

```
    barcode estim inhib inhib
            ated_ itor_ itor_
            backg code  conce
0 R00577279   113   IRB 0.001
1 R00577279   189   SNZ 0.001
2 R00577279   101   CMY 0.001
3 R00577279   112   BRC 0.001
4 R00577279   244   ISB 0.001
```

It's probably obvious that no single convention would be suitable for all situations, but, in any case, does `pandas` offer any way to customize the headers and column widths of a `DataFrame`'s display form?

Comment: I believe `pandas.set_option('max_colwidth',[desired-max])` should accomplish your needs, however it doesn't seem to work right now. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45883201/how-to-limit-width-of-column-headers-in-pandas) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack that uses the multi-index feature of pandas in a non-standard way, although I don't see any significant problems with doing that.  Of course, there is some increased complexity from using a multi-index rather than a simple index.

```
cols = df.columns
lencols = [ int(len(c)/2) for c in cols ]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( 
                 tuple( ( c[:ln], c[ln:] ) for c, ln in zip(cols, lencols) ) )
```

Results:

```
         bar  estimated_bac inhibit  inhibitor_c
        code kground_signal or_code oncentration
0  R00577279            133     IRB        0.001
1  R00577279            189     SNZ        0.001
2  R00577279            101     CMY        0.001
3  R00577279            112     BRC        0.001
4  R00577279            244     ISB        0.001
```

You could also consider creating a dictionary to convert between long & short names as needed:

- [Display column name different from dictionary key name in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243818/display-column-name-different-from-dictionary-key-name-in-pandas/48245015#48245015)

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously [pd.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html) display settings you can utilize. If you're looking for a pandas specific answer that doesn't involve changing notebook display settings, consider the below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), 
    columns=['Very Long Column Title ' + str(i) for i in range(2)])
df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector="th",props=[('max-width', '50px')])])
```